# How to inline style an embedded gist with CSS

Tags: html, css, github, gist

The following answer explains this for a CSS style sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535447/2263084

How can I do this as an inline style? (I am creating a webpage within a Wordpress site, do not have edit rights on the theme CSS file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a full style definition inside the html

```
<style type="text/css">
    .gist { width: 250px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Very good. Now my problem is that I want to control how much of the gist is displayed because the default is to show everything (which is pretty useless). I figured setting width and height styles would do this, and bring up scroll bars to show what is hidden. That works for width but for height it gives garbled output. Is there a way to fix that, or to style it a different way? It seems like an alternative script might be the way to do it? https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed

Comment: can you post a link to your example page to see the problem ?